# duvida com checkbox / angular

Tags: html, angularjs, table

Pessoal tenho essa table:

```
<table class="uk-table uk-table-nowrap">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center small_col"><input type="checkbox" icheck ng-model="table1.selectAll" class="check_all" table-check-all></th>
                            <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">User Image</th>
                            <th class="uk-width-2-10">User Name</th>
                            <th class="uk-width-2-10 uk-text-center">Order Number</th>
                            <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">Order Date</th>
                            <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">Status</th>
                            <th class="uk-width-2-10 uk-text-center">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uk-text-center uk-table-middle small_col"><input type="checkbox" icheck ng-model="table.row1" class="check_row" table-check-row></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><img class="md-user-image" ng-src="assets/img/avatars/avatar_01_tn.png" alt=""/></td>
                            <td>Valerie Barton</td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center">55/2015</td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center">13-11-1997</td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><span class="uk-badge uk-badge-success">Shipped</span></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center">
                                <a href="#"><i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE88F;</i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                         
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uk-text-center uk-table-middle small_col"><input type="checkbox" icheck ng-model="table.row7" class="check_row" table-check-row></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><img class="md-user-image" ng-src="assets/img/avatars/avatar_07_tn.png" alt=""/></td>
                            <td>Maximus Walsh</td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center">69/2015</td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center">08-05-1976</td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><span class="uk-badge uk-badge-success">Shipped</span></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center">
                                <a href="#"><i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE88F;</i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="uk-text-center uk-table-middle small_col"><input type="checkbox" icheck ng-model="table.row8" class="check_row" table-check-row></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><img class="md-user-image" ng-src="assets/img/avatars/avatar_08_tn.png" alt=""/></td>
                            <td>Zella Cummings</td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center">25/2015</td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center">14-01-1982</td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center"><span class="uk-badge uk-badge-primary">New</span></td>
                            <td class="uk-text-center">
                                <a href="#"><i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE88F;</i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Aqui um exemplo dela funcionando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Da forma que esta, permite selcionar varios checkbox (multiselect), preciso que quando selecionar um checkbox, desmarcar todos os outros, ou seja nao ser multiselect, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O comportamento que você busca é o mesmo comportamento do radio button. Posta seu JS ai, pra poder te responder melhor

Comment: fernandoocf, na vdd nao exite JS, apenas foi incluido um checkbox na table

Comment: então não tem nada de angular ai, correto?

Comment: muda o type do input pra type="checkbox"

Comment: de angular, por enquanto só o ng-repeat, e o type ja é checkbox, vc quiz dizer radiobuttom? eu preciso q seja um checkbox, pois em algum momento quero possibilitar ser multiselect, ou seja, ter um botao q habiita/desabilita o multiselect